# Using files as resources with URLClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, java-7, urlclassloader

I'm trying to write a Java 1.7 application that can be passed an arbitrary file from the command line. That file will be added to a ClassLoader so that it may be utilised as a resource.

Adding the file to a URLClassLoader seems to work, but how can I get that file as a resource after adding to the ClassLoader?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ClassLoaderTest {

  public static void main(String... args) throws MalformedURLException {

    File file = new File("/tmp/application.conf");
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
    System.out.println("ClassLoader URLs: " + Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));

    if (file.exists()) {
      System.out.println("File \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\" exists!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("File \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\" does not exist!");
      return;
    }

    URL url = classLoader.getResource(file.getAbsolutePath());

    System.out.println("File \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\" as url: " + url);

    assert url != null;

  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a ClassLoader? That's useful when the resource is in the same directory as a known class, but you shouldn't need to use anything other than a URL and a File if you just want to open the file and use it..

Comment: @PaulHicks The code that this will be integrated into expects to retrieve a resource from a ClassLoader, provided at initialisation.

Comment: I notice that your file isn't a jar. `URLClassLoader` works only with jars and directories of jars. You can either put your conf file into a jar, or implement your own class loader.

Comment: @PaulHicks Ahhh, I see. Then I probably need to implement my own ClassLoader, as requiring users of the app to package these files into jars is a little extreme.

Comment: Try providing the URL of the _directory_ to the class loader, then look for the file in the class loader using the path relative to that directory. The javadocs suggest to me that that should work. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to confirm this.

Comment: @PaulHicks Adding the directory parent to the URLClassLoader and then referencing the file by its name only worked. Amend your answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) supports only jar files and directories of files. So there are two options:

1. Put your resources into a jar file and add that jar file into your `URLClassLoader`.
2. Provide the directory to the class loader and use the relative path to the file from that directory.

Comment: And use paths that are rooted at the JAR root, not absolute pathnames. 'Only JAR files and directories of JAR files' isn't correct. If you name a directory it will find .class files and resources inside it or below it if the directory and package structures coincide.

Comment: Adding the directory and then getting the resource by file name worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.